# Creating an adjacency list with dictionaries

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

The question asks:
A graph can be represented in a file by listing one link per line, with each link represented by a pair of nodes. Write a function that reads such a file and returns an adjacency list (as a dictionary) for the graph. Notice that, for each line **A B** in the file, your function will need to insert node **B** into the list of neighbors **A** *and* insert node **A** into the list of neighbors of **B**. 
Example of a possible file:

```
graph.txt
A B
A C
A D
B E
C D
C E
```

I expect the final list to look something like this:

```
adjList = {
    A:    [B, C, D], 
    B:    [A, E],
    C:    [A, D, E], 
    D:    [A, C], 
    E:    [B, C], 
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: have you tried any code yet that you can show?

Comment: What's **your** question?

Comment: Hi please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make some edits to your question. Providing your code and what is your problem will really help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict to answer this question. I wrote the code and it is working but you may like to think about it first.

```
dictAdjacency=defaultdict(list)
with open('C:/graph.txt') as readObj:
    lines=readObj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        tempList=line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
        dictAdjacency[tempList[0]].append(tempList[1])
        dictAdjacency[tempList[1]].append(tempList[0])
print(dictAdjacency)
```

#### RESULT

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{
  'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 
  'B': ['A', 'E'], 
  'C': ['A', 'D', 'E'], 
  'D': ['A', 'C'], 
  'E': ['B', 'C']
})
```

Comment: could you elaborate? what am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to know whether the key exists. Just call append on the list that is created for you. btw, Your output does not match the requirement from the OP. Also, don't post pictures of text. Its not searchable.

Comment: My code does match his desired output. It's a dictionary and you can print it in your desired format.  Yes, looks like you can avoid checking the key existence .

Comment: In the desired output the key ‘B’ has two elements.

Comment: you are right, I changed the code to match the result. thank you

Comment: Ok, you got there. Now before I upvote, just replace the image of the output with the text of the output.